# meteorDown load testing output

Tags: performance, meteor, load

I am load testing my meteor app using meteorDown package. But it is not working as expected. Below is the code:

```
meteorDown.init(function (Meteor) {
   console.log("userId is:", Meteor.userId());
})

meteorDown.run({
  concurrency : 1,
  url : "http://localhost:3000"
})
```

Following is the output :

```
(node:10727) [DEP0016] DeprecationWarning: 'GLOBAL' is deprecated, use 
'global'
  --------------------------------------------------
     Time   : 2017-8-24 16:45:43
 --------------------------------------------------
   Time   : 2017-8-24 16:45:48
   --------------------------------------------------
```

Starting the test using this command : sudo meteor-down my_load_test.js.
This file is outside my app folder

Comment: this file is in my app folder only

Comment: What are you expecting to see?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, I know. Sorry about that.

I've recently been working with `meteor-down` and have experienced the same issue. For me, the issue was resolved simply by spinning up my application first. In my case, simply running the following resolved my issue:

`~$ meteor
~$ meteor-down my_load_test.js`

If `meteor-down` can't connect to the application, it seems to try incessantly without letting you know what the problem is.

In addition to that, I also noticed your use of `Meteor.userId()`. I can't say with any certainty that this is the case, but I *believe* you may need to  `meteor add meteorhacks:meteor-down` and configure it accordingly in order to have a user id at all. Just a thought.